# Blazor Server - how to disable identity registration page

Tags: blazor-server-side

Need the registration to be done programatically, therefore to disable the registration page from browser access.

How this can be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the solution explorer right click the project then select

> Add, New Scaffolded Item,
> Select Identity on the right,
> Check Account/Registration.
> Add the DBcontext in the dropdown then click Add.

> In the new Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml at the top put

```
@{
    // Stop users registering
    Response.Redirect("/");
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";

}
```

Then you will need to remove all the links in other files to registration page.